# how do I create a "blank" redirect page in HTML that has Google Analytics code in it?

Tags: html, redirect, google-analytics

How do I create a "blank" HTML page that redirects to a subfolder while still having the block of Google Analytics code in it so that Google Analytics can "see" the tracking code on the "home page"?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to redirect to the "blank" page then place your google code on the blank site then use javascript to redirect to wherever you want and make sure you have the same google analytics code on the landing page you are sending them.